# Can I Label breakpoints in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to name(label) breakpoints in MS VS 2008?

I know 2010 has that feature but, I am still stuck with 2008 at work as I am not sure what would the overhead be to go from 2008 to 2010.

What tempted me to post this question here was that, there is a column called "name" wheich seems to be grayed out.

I'm guessing this would probably let me achieve what I want but I am not sure how to enable this.

Edit 1: I am trying working with C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the msdn documentation, no.

There is an msdn article about labeling breakpoints:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293674.aspx

It describes how to do it for VS 2010.  There is a dropdown at the top of the screen that says "Other Versions" and only allows you to select VS 2012.  So no, you can't do it in VS 2008.  Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for this. But are there any workarounds? What does the "name" column signify?

Comment: I sincerely doubt there's a workaround.  It was added in VS 2010 so it won't be a feature in older versions.  What do you mean by "What does the name column signify"?

Comment: In the breakpoints window, it lets me select(customize) a list of columns to be displayed. In that I see "name" as one of the options but it is grayed out (implying I can't add that as a column).

In 2010 version of MS VS at home, Under the "Name" column it mentions my filename.cpp and line number.